# How to run a script from another path, and know the script's path?

Tags: shell, scripting, shell-script, path

I need to run a script that access a file in the same path it is located.

For example: I have the script in `/home/me/folder/script.sh`, and this script will access the file `/home/me/folder/myfile`. As the file is in the same path of the script, I just use the name `myfile`, not the full path.

But if I run it from `/tmp/`, like:

```
/tmp$ /home/me/folder/script.sh
```

it gives me:

```
myfile: No such file or directory
```

So, how can I say in the script that the file is in the same path as the script itself?

Comment: Can you show what the usage of myfile is here?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: is just another script that my script.sh calls.

Comment: Some reason you don't want to use the full path, or move both of these into your PATH?

Comment: @Faheem Mitha: I want to be able to move this folder with the scripts to another place, maybe even another computer, without need to rewrite myfile's path.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about `$(dirname "$0")/myfile`?

Answer (score 9):

You can't know in all circumstances, but often (not always) when you run a script by path instead of letting the shell search `$PATH`, the path to the script will be in `$0`.  You can then use `dirname "$0"` or `${0%/*}` to get the path.

Answer (score 4):

I would normally do something like this at the head of my script:

```
SCRIPTDIR=$(dirname "$0")
```

Or, to get the full pathname to the script's directory (instead of a relative pathname):

```
SCRIPTDIR=$(cd $(dirname "$0") && pwd)
```

Then just reference `${SCRIPTDIR}` where needed.